# std::map calls default constructor on [], copy constructor on insert()

Tags: c++, stdmap

My std::map is called uniformBlocks. I was testing out the way to add new elements when I noticed something weird. When I add new key, value pair using the method below:

```
uniformBlocks["MatrixBlock"] = matrixBlock;
```

The default constructor is called.  However, when I use insert, the copy constructor is called, which is expected.

```
uniformBlocks.insert(
    std::pair<const std::string, glWrapper::UBO>("MatrixBlock", matrixBlock)
);
```

Why is there a difference between the two methods. Aren't they implemented the same way under the hood?

Comment: Once constructs in place with the copy-ctor, the other default-constructs, then copy-assigns. So no, they're not the same under the hood.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks very much. Do you know which one is faster? Also, please post your answer so I can accept it

Comment: What exactly prevents you from trying either approach, and then timing the results to see which one is faster?

Comment: @ManhNguyen Yakk covered it nicely. I'm *certain* this is a dupe (nearly all library and language questions these days are), but i just don't have the time to look for it. Glad it helped. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[]` creates an object if it does not exist then returns a reference to it.  At that time, no arguments are available.

`=` then assigns to this reference.

`insert` has no need to do that.  It can simply construct in place using the pair you pass in.

With careful use, `emplace` can even do away with the copy or move ctor call.

Comment: Also important, `insert` had the added benefit of returning a tasty piece of data informing the caller of whether the key existed prior, and regardless of that, the iterator position in the map of the inserted element. the `std::pair<iterator, bool>` returned from `insert` can come in *very* handy.