# Default constructor of the structure for correct std::map behaviour

Tags: c++, c++03

Why do we need to define the default constructor `TConcrete()` for the correct `std::map` behaviour?
Without it I got the following:

```
 >note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair<std::tuple<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &&>,std::tuple<>,0,>(_Tuple1 &,_Tuple2 &,std::integer_sequence<unsigned int,0>,std::integer_sequence<::size_t>)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=std::string,
1>            _Ty=TConcrete,
1>            _Tuple1=std::tuple<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &&>,
1>            _Tuple2=std::tuple<>
1>        ]
```

Here is the code I have. I am using *C++03*.

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include"TBuilder.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TBuilder builder = TBuilder();
    cout << builder.Get_Eb("B25");
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**TBuilder.h**

```
#pragma once
#include"TConcrete.h"

class TBuilder {
private:
    TConcreteData concrete_data;
public:
         TBuilder();
    double Get_Eb(string);
};
```

**TBuilder.cpp**

```
#include"TBuilder.h"

TBuilder::TBuilder()
{
    TConcrete B25 = TConcrete( "B25",2000,20,2 );
    concrete_data["B25"] = B25;
}

double TBuilder::Get_Eb(string grade0)
{
    return concrete_data[grade0].E_b;
}
```

**TConcrete.h**

```
#pragma once

#include<map>
#include<string>
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

struct TConcrete {
    string grade;
    double E_b, R_b, R_bt;
    TConcrete();
    TConcrete(string, double,double,double);
};   
typedef map<string, TConcrete> TConcreteData;
```

**TConcrete.cpp**

```
#include "TConcrete.h"

TConcrete::TConcrete()
{
}

TConcrete::TConcrete(string grade0, double E_b0, double R_b0, double Rb_t0)
{
    grade = grade0;
    E_b = E_b0;
    R_b = R_b0;
    R_bt = R_b0;
}
```

I read [std::map calls default constructor on [], copy constructor on insert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770098/stdmap-calls-default-constructor-on-copy-constructor-on-insert) discussion but using `insert()`required the default constructor as well. See the code with `insert()`.

**TConcrete.h** (mofified with `insert()`)

```
#pragma once

#include<map>
#include<string>
#include "main.h"
#include<utility>

using namespace std;

struct TConcrete {
    string grade;
    double E_b, R_b, R_bt;
    TConcrete();
    TConcrete(string, double,double,double);
};
typedef map<string, TConcrete> TConcreteData;
typedef pair<string, TConcrete> TConcreteDataItem;
```

**TBuilder.cpp** (mofified with `insert()`)

```
#include"TBuilder.h"

TBuilder::TBuilder()
{
    TConcrete B25 = TConcrete( "B25",2000,20,2 );
    concrete_data.insert(TConcreteDataItem("B25",B25));
}

double TBuilder::Get_Eb(string grade0)
{
    return concrete_data[grade0].E_b;
}
```

Comment: Where is your `std::map`?

Comment: This code isn't complete - you don't show any `std::map` declarations. But assuming TConcreteData is some kind of type alias for a `std::map`, `std::map::operator[]` inserts a new object into the map if the key accessed doesn't exist. If you don't want your TConcrete class to be default-constructible, you have to use other functions, like `std::map::emplace`

Comment: What is TConcreteData?

Comment: @JamesPicone You are right. I missed `typedef` in **TConcrete.h** when moved the code from VS. Corrected.

Comment: @Fëamarto See my answer to JamesPicone

Comment: @taskinoor See my answer to JamesPicone

Comment: @JamesPicone I am using **C++03**. No `std::map::emplace` is available in this version.

Comment: @JamesPicone According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map `emplace()` is available since **C++11**

Comment: @maksim_volodin in C++03, you can use `std::map::insert()`

Comment: That is **not** what I understand as a "minimal" example, as in [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a default constructor because of the way you are using `std::map` requires it to possibly create objects. If you don't use it in such a way default constructors are not necessary.

This code will not compile due to the lack of default constructors:

```
#include <map>

struct Struct
{
    Struct(int) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Struct > m;
    m["1"] = Struct(1);
    Struct& s = m["1"];
}
```

The `[]` operator returns a reference to an existing value. If that value doesn't exist a new one is created (using the default constructor) and a reference to that is returned. The first statement might not look like this is what's going on but is actually equivalent to:

```
Struct& s = m["1"];
s = Struct(1);
```

If you use `find` and `insert` instead no default constructor is required:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, Struct > m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("1"), Struct(1)));
    auto it = m.find("1");
    if (it != m.end())
    {
        Struct& s = it->second;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with `insert()`. May you have a look?

Comment: @maksim_volodin You are still using the `[]` operator in `Get_Eb`, you can't use that operator unless your types are default construcible

Answer (score 3):

`std::map::operator[]` searches for the specified key, and if not found then it inserts a new *default-constructed* value for that key.

As such, the statement `concrete_data["B25"]` always returns a valid `TConcrete&` reference, which means default-constructing a `TConcrete` object if needed, before allowing you to assign your `B25` variable to the found/inserted value.

If you want to add a new key to a map without searching if the key already exists, use `std::map::insert()` or `std::map::emplace()` instead:

```
TConcrete B25( "B25", 2000, 20, 2 );
concrete_data.insert(std::make_pair("B25", B25));
```

```
TConcrete B25( "B25", 2000, 20, 2 );
concrete_data.emplace("B25", B25);
```

Comment: In fact, I tested `std::map::insert()` before placing the question and it does not work. See the updated question.

Comment: @maksim_volodin `insert()` does not require your `TConcrete` class to have a default constructor. If you are getting an error on that statement when no default constructor is defined, then please show that error. However, `concrete_data[grade0]` does require a default constructor

Comment: @Remi Lebeau As it was ponted out by Alan Birtles *"You are still using the [] operator in Get_Eb, you can't use that operator unless your types are default construcible"* Now I suppose this subject is clear for me.